# install Confluent on Openshift on aws

Tags: apache-kafka, openshift, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

I am trying to install Confluent on Openshift on aws ,
and following the documentation
https://docs.confluent.io/5.4.2/installation/operator/co-deployment.html#co-download-the-bundle, and while installing the zookeeper (step 2) , its failing with following.

```
oc describe zookeeper zookeeper
==================================
Status:
  Current Replicas:  0
  Phase:             PENDING
  Ready Replicas:    0
  Reason:            PROVISIONING
  Replicas:          0
Events:
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Any reason not to use https://strimzi.io , which is built by RedHat and tested on OpenShift?

Comment: And if you don't want Strimzi, I think the page you're using is old since this is the latest release of "Confluent For Kubernetes" - https://docs.confluent.io/operator/current/co-deploy-cfk.html